# Spyware for Windows or Android

Tags: windows, android, spyware

Are there any software or applications that can take a snap when an incorrect PIN/PASSWORD is used to log in to the system.

- The program should take a pic and store in the hard drive or cloud.
- Should support autostart
- Premium or Open source(anything is fine)
- Should support multiple formats in saving the picture

Is there any such software for Windows and Android?

Comment: For Android there's be e.g. [Lockwatch](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bloketech.lockwatch) or [SmSimApp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mediahouselb.smsimapp) taking a photo with the front-cam on unsuccessful unlock attempts. No idea about Windows, though.

Comment: In Windows you can track incorrect logon information in Event Viewer (Event ID 4625)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Third Eye](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.miragestacks.thirdeye&hl=en_US) for Android.

Their feature list includes, quoted from their list:

- The app automatically takes a photo while someone enters the wrong
  PIN, Pattern or Password.
- Notification about wrong attempts while you unlock the lock screen.
- Last Unlock Time feature will show you the previous lock screen
  unlock time. With that, you can easily find if someone used your
  mobile without your knowledge.
- A detailed photo logs of the mobile snoopers.
- A lot more customization settings.

Additionally for windows, as mentioned by batistuta09, you can check login attempts in the event viewer on windows. The guides below are helpful if you don't know how to use the event viewer.

[Check Successful or Failed Windows Login Attempts](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/check-windows-logon-events-windows-8/)

[How to See Who Logged Into a Computer (and When)](https://www.howtogeek.com/124313/how-to-see-who-logged-into-a-computer-and-when/)